# Shape of pendulum bob

Tags: experimental-physics

Why are pendulum bobs spherical, and not any other shape, like cubical?
We were asked to perform an experiment and calculate the approximate value of g using a pendulum, by the formula 
T=2pi(l/g)^(1/2)
My teacher asked me this question and I was unable to answer it. Does it have something to do with the fact that surface area will be minimised in a sphere?

Comment: Surely the simplest aerodynamic shape without bothering of orientation

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Physics SE.

As pointed out by Alchimista, the spherical shape is required to minimize air resistance which may slow down the bob of the pendulum.

The spherical shape is also good because it provides this aerodynamic effect from both the sides.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal This is indeed this is the reason for that. Not to mention that a cubic (or a different shape whatsoever) tends to spin very quickly due to the imperfection about where the center of mass is inside creating a torque. Telling you this cos i tried. Remember that the formula you use for the period is valid only at small angle (<~ 23°, where you will start to measure a longer period of about 1%).